# Change Number data to alphabet from array

Tags: php, arrays

I have Array data like this

```
$corect_position=array(
        'A' => '0',
        'B' => '1',
        'C' => '2',
        'D' => '3',
        'E' => '4'
        );
```

and i have number data like this

```
 $corect_key = '012301230123';
```

how to equate the data in the string with the data in the array so that later what appears is
A B C D

Comment: str_split, loop, profit

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to generate new string which will contain keys from `$corect_position`?

```
<?php
$corect_position=array(
    'A' => '0',
    'B' => '1',
    'C' => '2',
    'D' => '3',
    'E' => '4'
    );

$corect_key = '012301230123';

$corect_arr = str_split($corect_key);
$new_corect = '';

foreach($corect_arr as $corect){
    if(($key = array_search($corect, $corect_position)) !== false){
        $new_corect .= $key;
    }else{
        // Not found in array
    }
}

print_r($new_corect);
```

Output :

```
ABCDABCDABCD
```

Tell me if you want anything else.

Answer (score 0):

```
   <?php
    $corect_position=array(
        'A' => '0',
        'B' => '1',
        'C' => '2',
        'D' => '3',
        'E' => '4'
    );

    $corect_key = '012301230123';

    $array_corect_key  = array_map(null, str_split($corect_key));

    foreach($array_corect_key as $key){
        foreach($corect_position as $position) {
            if($key == $position){
               echo array_keys($corect_position, $position)[0];
               continue;
            }
        }
    }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple one-line solution:

```
$corect_position=array(
        'A' => '0',
        'B' => '1',
        'C' => '2',
        'D' => '3',
        'E' => '4'
        );
$corect_key = '012301230123';

echo str_replace(array_values($corect_position), array_keys($corect_position), $corect_key );
```

Output:

```
ABCDABCDABCD
```

Also notice the word "correct" should be spelled with 2 R's.

Answer (score 0):

```html
$output = '';
foreach($corect_position as $key) {
 $output.=$key;
}

echo $output;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [strtr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtr.php) function after flipping the 1st array

```
 echo strtr($corect_key, array_flip($corect_position)); // ABCDABCDABCD
```

[demo](https://eval.in/940450)